# Retrofit returning NULL Response

Tags: java, android, android-studio, retrofit

Here is my code, what am I doing wrong?

DeviceFetcher.java

```
public class DeviceFetcher extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String BASE_URL = "https://base-url/";
 
    public static void fetchDevices() {

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        String token = SplashScreen.getTOKEN();
        ApiService apiService = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);

        Call<DeviceResponse> call = apiService.getDevices("jwt" + token);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<DeviceResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<DeviceResponse> call, Response<DeviceResponse> response) {
                Log.e("DEVICEFETCHER", "Response: " + response.body());
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    DeviceResponse responseData = response.body();
                    if (responseData != null) {
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("NO RESPONSE = NULL");
                    // Handle API error
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<DeviceResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("DEVICEFETCHER", "Error: " + t.getLocalizedMessage());
              
            }
        });
    }
}
```

ApiService.java

```
public interface ApiService {
    String BASE_URL = "https://base-url/";
    String accessToken = SplashScreen.getTOKEN();
    @GET("devices")
    Call<DeviceResponse> getDevices(@Header("Authorization") String authHeader);
}
```

I am not getting any response from the above calls, it shows response as NULL. What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Comment: Please try to run it on **Postman** first, If NULL still there then your server has some problem, and you need to corporate with your team  to see if this service need any more QUERY or PARAMS.. etc

Comment: Mention the error message so that we can help you.